# Determining what this Delete Statement does

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Not really a sql programmer. It looks to me that its looking for anything where exch_date is today and deleting it. Is that correct?

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Table where 
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,exch_Date),0) = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to validate this is to input it into a select statement.  This will help you identify all the rows that will be affected.

```
Select * from db.table
where DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,exch_Date), 0)
    = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: wow, that is excellent. I will definitely use this in the future!

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be doing a whole day (as in no time component) comparison between exch_Date and the current date.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could give two answers

Answer (score 1):

That's what it's doing. Here's another way that treats the dates as numbers, instead of working with the date manipulation functions:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Table WHERE 
CAST( CAST(exch_Date as float) as int ) = CAST( CAST(getdate() as float) as int )
```

Note: I had originally had this:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Table WHERE 
CAST( exch_Date as int ) = CAST( getdate() as int )
```

But as Andriy pointed out in the comments, this will round up to the next noon, rather than simply truncate the date to an integer. By going through the float conversion first, the integer cast behaves as expected. Andriy's solution of subtracting 0.5 also works fine, although I prefer the slightly more long-winded float version, which avoids any potential magic-number confusion down the road.

Comment: Sir, I firmly believe you are mistaken here. `CAST(datetimevalue AS int)` will round the float-numbered representation of `datetimevalue` to the nearest integer. You'll have to do it like this: `CAST(datetimevalue - 0.5 AS int)` in order to get the datepart's integer equivalent.

Comment: Andriy, you're right; I forgot about that next-noon rounding behavior. You can also get around it by going through `float`, which has the effect of chopping off the time in the expected way. I'm modifying the answer accordingly, and thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, the best solution by far is to CAST to date, which is still SARGable (can use index)

```
DELETE db.table
where CAST(exch_Date as Date) = DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE())
```

The `DateAdd to 0` portion is redundant (extraneous) code.

Prior to SQL Server 2008, you are better off for performance reasons to always test a date/time column against a range than to use a function on it resulting in table scan.

```
DELETE db.table
where exch_Date >= DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE())
  and exch_Date <  DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()) +1
```